# How do i concat dataframes without duplicates however keeping duplicates in the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add rows from DF2 to DF1, only if they don't already exist in DF1, based on colA. Basically, don't add the row into DF1 if the column value of ColA already exists.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'colA': [10,10, 20, 30],
                     'colB': [100, 20, 300,54],
                     'colC': [100, 20, 300,67]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'colA': [40, 20, 50],
                     'colB': [400, 200, 500]})
```

this is what I have so far:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(["colA"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The reason `drop_duplicates` doesn't work well for me is that I need the duplicates in df1 to remain.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2['colA'].isin(df1['colA'])]])` ..?

Comment: thanks that was so easy!

Comment: you should put it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @jezrael `20` is in `df1`, so shouldnt be added from `df2`

Comment: @ChrisA - ya, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with NOT logical operator `~` to filter the rows from `df2` to append:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2['colA'].isin(df1['colA'])]], ignore_index=True)
```

[out]

```
   colA  colB   colC
0    10   100  100.0
1    10    20   20.0
2    20   300  300.0
3    30    54   67.0
4    40   400    NaN
5    50   500    NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

> This may help you.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'colA': [10,10, 20, 30],
                     'colB': [100, 20, 300,54],
                     'colC': [100, 20, 300,67]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'colA': [40, 20, 50],
                     'colB': [400, 200, 500]})

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], join="outer").reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

> Here is the output.

```
   colA  colB   colC
0    10   100  100.0
1    10    20   20.0
2    20   300  300.0
3    30    54   67.0
4    40   400    NaN
5    20   200    NaN
6    50   500    NaN
```